# uninitialized constant Guard::Dsl::Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm unable to find an answer online to this.  This is the error I'm getting when trying to run `bundle exec guard`

```
00:53:52 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is: 
> [#] 
> [#] uninitialized constant Guard::Dsl::Minitest, 
> [#] backtrace: 
> [#]   (dsl)> ./Guardfile:27:in `block in evaluate'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:178:in `guard'
> [#]   (dsl)> ./Guardfile:26:in `evaluate'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:377:in `instance_eval'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:377:in `evaluate'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:91:in `evaluate'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard.rb:134:in `_evaluate'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard.rb:49:in `setup'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/commander.rb:32:in `start'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/cli/environments/valid.rb:16:in `start_guard'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/cli.rb:113:in `start'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:32:in `execute'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:19:in `execute!'
> [#]   (dsl)> /home/user/.rvm/rubygems/guard-2.12.5/bin/_guard-core:11:in `<main>'
```

This is the `Guardfile`

```
guard :minitest do
  with Minitest::Unit
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test' }

  #with Minitest::Spec
  # watch(%r{^spec/(.*)_spec\.rb$})
  # watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})         { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  # watch(%r{^spec/spec_helper\.rb$}) { 'spec' }

  # Rails 4
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                               { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb"                }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/application_controller\.rb$}) { 'test/controllers'                        }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_controller\.rb$})        { |m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb"    }
  watch(%r{^app/bridges/(.+)_bridge\.rb$})                { |m| "test/bridges/#{m[1]}_test.rb"        } 
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)_mailer/.+})                    { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_mailer_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                               { |m| "test/lib/#{m[1]}_test.rb"            }
  watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})                       { 'test'                                    }

  # Rails < 4
  # watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb$}) { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  # watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  # watch(%r{^app/models/(.*)\.rb$})      { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
end
```

And in my Gemfile I have both `gem 'guard'` and `gem 'guard-minitest'` in `test` and `development` groups.

I don't see any documentation for this in the minitest, guard, or guard-minitest githubs.  Why is it expecting Guard::Dsl::Minitest and why can't I find that in the source code for guard-minitest?

- Rails 4.1.10
- Ruby 2.2.1
- guard 2.12.5
- guard-compat 1.2.1
- guard-minitest 2.4.4

This is my first experience trying to use guard.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a hunch but comment the with Minitest::Unit in the Guardfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment above re commenting "with Minitest::Unit" i.e. "#with .."